# When to consider code efficiency in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, functional-programming, big-o

These days, I am learning different Java code efficiencies (big-O) in school.
I couldn't help but wonder when to consider code efficiency in a real world programming.

Is it something that programmers think about during the PDL/Pseudo stage?
or just as you are writing the code..

I'd appreciate your thoughts on this!

Comment: I use it to choose between collections.  The rest of the time I measure.

Comment: StackOverflow is for questions about programming problems. Try Programmers StackExchange.

Comment: Only when it matters.  And (surprisingly) it often DOESN'T matter.

Comment: You should consider efficiency when you know it's a problem because you measured it.

Comment: @StephenC not only; often it doesn't matter but when you measure it, the performance problem is not where you could have predicted it.

Comment: I think you are trying to make a distinction between "considering" because you need to and out of necessity and out of intellectual curiosity.  Frankly, I don't think we should be in the business of instructing people when they need to satisfy their curiosity ... except to say "not on company time"!

Comment: My original point is that it is often not even worthwhile measuring performance.

Comment: If anybody selectively quotes Don Knuth here I will scream.

Comment: `different Java code efficiencies (big-O)`: Java _implementations_ of, e.g., abstract data type operations will use algorithms, one of which will decide any given bound of complexity as some measure of problem size tends to infinity. Big-O of any given algorithm does _not_ depend on implementation language (if that language isn't too far from the machine model implied - say, no "constant" time multiplication primitive or bit storage, only).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note that what follows is fairly generic since the question is quite fundamental.*

In the real world programmers tend to look at efficiency during the design phase typically when:

- the problem they are solving is time-critical (e.g.: video rendering and image processing)
- the amount of data they are handling is too large (e.g.: analyzing billions of strings from a feed)

Else they mostly use 'off the shelf' methods and design principles.

In some cases, code-review catches poor implementations from inexperienced developers and there is a considerable amount of rework and learning :)

Sometimes some existing implementations are performance intensive and they are so because of various reasons (poor knowledge, time constraints, 'it was a good idea at that time', unclear understanding of problem etc.). In such cases there are often a post-mortem fix-up of the implementation and in those cases also there are better implementations and efficiencies considered.

Also note the famous quotes from Knuth:

*We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%*

and

*In established engineering disciplines a 12% improvement, easily obtained, is never considered marginal and I believe the same viewpoint should prevail in software engineering*

So there needs to be a balance within time investment, complexity and optimization. For more information read up the [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization).

Answer (score 1):

If you can see at the PDL stage that the complexity is going to be O(2^n) or even O(n^2) for very large n then you'd think again, but even then you might prototype those bits just to see what happens.

Normally you get the thing right first, because you can't really tell how fast it will be until it's right, and then you use a profiler (e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/samples/hprof.html for a very simple example) to see where it is actually burning the cpu and then concentrate on those bits.

Answer (score 0):

Big O notation is a great way of expressing the efficiency of an algorithm, but when dealing with code in an enterprise system things usually get more complicated.  The architecture of the system as a whole, and the infrastructure it's running on will probably have more of an impact (and be more expensive to fix) in the long run due to [performance and stability problems](https://broadek.co.uk/blog/DealingWithPerformanceAndStabilityIssues) if they're wrong.

Big O notation is certainly something engineers would think about (or in terms of) when they've identified a bottleneck using performance analysers and other tools, and are looking to implement a more efficient algorithm in the area where that bottleneck is.